# How the nearest-neighbor interpolation works on 2D (upscaling)

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, nearest-neighbor

I have a small doubt about the [nearest-neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) method:

Suppose we have a grayscale image of size 2x2 pixels, which can be represented by the following matrix:

```
[100, 120]
[080, 100]
```

And we want to resize it to the size of 3x3 pixels:

```
[100, X, 120]
[  X, X,   X]
[080, X, 100]
```

How will the missing data points (pixels) be filled?

Will it just replicate the first nearest data point (pixel)?
For example:

```
[100, 100, 120]
[100, 100, 120]
[080, 080, 100]
```

Or, will it calculate the average between the two nearest neighbors?
For example:

```
[100, 110, 120]
[090, 100, 110]
[080, 090, 100]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replicate. Averaging would be bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I have another doubt. When I have an odd number of pixels and the 'distance' between the two nearest neighbors are equal (like the example in the question), should I always replicate the left (or upper in case of columns) pixel? Thanks

Comment: @KelvinS: how you round is up to you. The IEEE round function typically rounds half-way values towards zero, meaning that you'd pick the pixel on the left or top. As long as you're consistent, it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is application dependent. Either it makes no difference from the standpoint of the application and you just don't care (use any rule), or it does make a difference, and the difference it makes will tell you what rule to adopt.